# Bitcoin Dictionary

Tags: websites, standard, academic-research, terminology

Is there a website that aggregates all technical and jargon terms used by the Bitcoin community? In other words, is there some compact reference guide that could serve as a "Bitcoin Dictionary"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vocabulary

Comment: It looks like that page is highly technical. I wonder if there is non-technical jargon that is missing.